# Prove surjectivity using the injective property.

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Let's say that we have a function $f:\mathbb{M} \rightarrow \mathbb{M}$ where $\mathbb{M}$  is an arbitrary set. And let's say that the function f is injective.Does that mean that the function is surjective too? More generally: If a function's domain and codomain coincide and the function is injective does that imply that the function is surjective?
My way of thinking this:
 Suppose that f is not surjective $\Rightarrow \exists y \in \mathbb{M}$ such that $f(x) \neq y, \forall x \in \mathbb{M}$ And since the domain and the codomain coincide this mean that two elements from domain must go in the exact element from the codomain which implies that f is not injective, which is a contradiction. Therefore f is surjective. Am I right? Thanks

Comment: Not if $\mathbb M$ is infinite.  Consider $f: \mathbb Z\to \mathbb Z$ given by $f(n)=2n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works in sets of finite cardinality, but fails in sets of infinite cardinality.

For instance consider the map

$\phi: \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$

such that $\phi: n\to 2n$. This is injective but not surjective: $3$ is never mapped to.